# $ g\circ f$ injective $\implies$ $f$ injective or $g$ injective

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

First I have to prove that:

If $g\circ f$ injective $\implies$ $f$ injective **or** $g$ injective

And real functions that improve:

If $g\circ f$ injective $\implies$ $f$ injective **and** $g$ injective

I was thinking about $\sqrt x$ and $x^2$, so that $g\circ f$ will be bijective, but I don't really sure about that example

Comment: Go down to the definition of injective; if $gf$ is injective then $gf(x) = gf(x') \Rightarrow x = x'$.

Comment: Different variations of this question have been asked countless times on this site.

Comment: "And real functions that improve:"  What does that phrase mean?  That you have to come up with examples where this is true?  Your example is fine except $x^2$ is not injective on R.  It is on $[0, \infty$ or $(-\infty, 0]$ and others though. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof for: If $g\circ f$ injective $\implies$ $f$ injective

> Logically this proves that "If $g\circ f$ injective $\implies$ $f$ injective **or** $g$ injective" but no need to $g$-injective part, as your example says.

If not, there is x and y such that $x\ne y$ but $f(x)= f(y).$ So  $g \circ f(x)= g \circ f(y).$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = f(y) \implies (g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y) \implies x = y$. Thus $f$ is injective. The condition $g$ is injective is not necessary. Example: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}, g(x) = x^2$ as you mentioned.

Comment: Is that fair? The domain of f is the nonnegatives but the implied domain of g is all reals.Is there any stipulations or restrictions on the domains of f, g and g(f())? g does have to be injective on the image of f but it doesn't need to have its domain restricted to the image of f. But it seems kind of cheating to arbitrarily make up a larger domain for g. Ex.f(x)=x.  g:R$\cup${elephants}; g(x)=x if x is real; g(x)=1 if x is an elephant, somehow doesn't seem fair.Or is that the point; g can always have a domain larger than the image of f and thus nothing can ever be said about its injectivity.